# Android:  Does it possible to block google sync service only for contacts synchronization?

Tags: android

I heard that Google read  my contact list  and synchronized them with android.process.contacts . How can I block it  and what are the disadvantages from this blocking? I want to use onkly synchronization for gmail.

Comment: Why you want to block google sync service?

Comment: I dont want to synchronized my contacts, but I just want to synchronized gmail. Does it possible to block google sync service only for contacts synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
I've managed to do it pretty much by doing the following (as mentioned above):
1) Backup as much as possible
2) Factory Reset (to clear association with Google account)
3) Set up phone with a dummy google account by doing Create rather than sign in (leave this Google account with no contacts/calendar etc).
4) Go to the calendar and then Menu -> More -> Calendars -> Menu and remove the Google calendar (I just use the PC sync one).
5) Market will require a Google account so you can create the dummy account through there if you haven't already.
6) Go to GoogleMail application and then Menu -> Accounts -> Add account and then sign in with your main account.
There it will then ask if you want to sync mail and contacts (gives you the option!!) and just sync mail.
7) You can then select that account and GMail will always go to that account but contacts/calendar are still linked in with the dummy account.
8) Go to Maps and then Menu -> More -> Switch Account and go to your other GMail account to get any stored starred places from that account.
9) You can then go into Settings -> Accounts and Sync and turn off sync for the dummy account if preferred.
```

I find that if you clear contact storage in Applications that it'll then suck in all the contacts from the secondary account. In which case you need to remove the account again from accounts and sync and add it back in in the Google Mail application.

Hope that's helpful to anyone else that may want to do this...